# SQLAlchemy column defined by 'column_property' not showing up when accessing the model's columns

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I want a column, `total` in my sqlalchemy model that is equal to `amount * price`. The column value can be accessed by `object.total` but the column name doesn't show up in `model.__table__.columns.keys()`

I have tried setting total as a hybrid_property and a column_property. Neither works to include the column when I access the columns.

This is my model:

```
class RawMaterials(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'raw_materials'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = db.Column(db.String(64))
    product = db.Column(db.String(64))
    amount = db.Column(db.Integer)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer)
    total = column_property(amount * price)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<id:{} product:{}>'.format(self.id, self.product)
```

and this is where I query the model for columns:

```
@app.route('/tables')
@login_required
def tables(methods=["GET", "POST"]):
    if request.args.get('data'):
        table = request.args.get('data').lower().replace(" ","_")
    else:
        table = 'raw_materials'
    database = get_db_model(table)
    materials = database.query.all()
    columns = database.__table__.columns.keys()
    new_mats = format_data(materials, columns)
    title = table.replace("_", " ").upper()
    return render_template('tables.html.j2', title=title, materials=materials, columns=columns)
```

If I print out the `columns` variable into the console, it returns:
`['id', 'type', 'product', 'amount', 'price']`
and I want it to return:
`['id', 'type', 'product', 'amount', 'price', 'total']`

I expect total to be in the columns but it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `column_property()` function, you need to make sure that 
 the expression is compatible with the `SELECT` statement emitted for your `RawMaterials` class. You can try to use a [Hybrid](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-a-hybrid), instead.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

class RawMaterials(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'raw_materials'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = db.Column(db.String(64))
    product = db.Column(db.String(64))
    amount = db.Column(db.Integer)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<id:{} product:{}>'.format(self.id, self.product)

    @hybrid_property
    def total(self):
        return self.amount * self.price
```

Here the `total` property returns the multiplication of the `amount` and `price` attributes. With an instance of `RawMaterials`, this multiplication occurs in Python, using standard Python descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the entity's `__table__`'s columns will only return the columns on the database table.  Pseudo-columns created by the ORM can be accessed via the entity's [mapper](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper).

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import inspect
>>> 
>>> mapper = inspect(RawMaterials)
>>> mapper.columns.keys()
['total', 'id', 'type', 'product', 'amount', 'price']
```